# Entity Framework Core - Code First - Two Foreign Keys - One Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core.  I want my base class to keep reference of CreateByUser, and LastModifiedByUser.  Unfortunately I can only get it to work with one foreign key.  When I try to add a second foreign key I get this error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Assignments_Users_LastModifiedByUserId' on table 'Assignments' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.  Note that I can use "Add-Migration" with out any errors, but once I run "Update-Database" it errors.

Below is the relevant code to the problem and error.

```
public abstract class DivBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset DateCreated { get; set; }

    public int CreatedByUserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset LastDateModified { get; set; }

    public int LastModifiedByUserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedByUserId")]
    public DivUser CreatedByUser { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LastModifiedByUserId")]
    public DivUser LastModifiedByUser { get; set; }
}

public class DivUser
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class DivAssignment : DivBase, IDivEvent
{
    public DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset EndDate { get; set; }      
}

public interface IDivEvent
{
    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Also, If I make one of the properties nullable it will compile, but I fear that will cause problems later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have a 2 `Fk`s to the same table in the same `row` so imagine if you delete a user who has created an assignment and Modified one what should happen, delete the assignment what if other users modified it this will be nulls in heir tables.

so

You need to specify the `CascadeOnDelete` to `false` using `FluentApi`

In the `ApplicationContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<DivAssignment>()
                .HasRequired(c => c.CreatedByUser)
                .WithMany(u => u.CreatedDivAssignments)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.CreatedByUserId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<DivAssignment>()
                .HasRequired(c => c.LastModifiedByUser)
                .WithMany(u => u.ModifiedDivAssignments)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.LastModifiedByUserId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
```

Then `add-migration` then `update-database`

Comment: of course I recommend using `FluentAPI ` as it is much more rich than `DataAnnotations`

Comment: Ahmed, is that syntax for Entity Framework Core? Because my Visual studio did not recognize hasRequired, withMany, or the rest

Comment: Hi @TomCrosman 

First I tried this and it worked, Actually I made the whole project just for you..
Second Yes its in `visualStudio` but you need to add this in the `DBContext` of your project

Comment: I tried to add it to my DBContext.  I think the problem is that these syntaxes are the wrong version of EntityFramework (I’m using entity Framework Core)

Comment: @TomCrosman
I added a [Git Link](https://github.com/medotec/DivProject.git)

Comment: Ahmed, Thank you for all the effort.  I chose your answer, but once again i'll point out that you are not using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore but instead System.Data.Entity.

Comment: Ef Core should be like this  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);